# How To detect empty argument list for variadric function (va_arg, va_end, va_start)

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, argument-passing

I have a function that encapsulate the [CString::FormatV](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ysfhy4h5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function, and I need to be able to detect if an empty parameter list is passed to the function. What's the best way to do this?

My current code goes like this

```
CString ADString::Format(CString csFormat, ...)
{
    //Code comes from CString::Format()
    CString csReturn;
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, csFormat);
    csReturn.FormatV(csFormat, argList);
    va_end( argList );
    return csReturn;
}
```

and I would like something like that

```
CString ADString::Format(CString csFormat, ...)
{
    //Code comes from CString::Format()
    CString csReturn;
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, csFormat);
    //If it's empty, don't send to FormatV
    if(!IsArgListEmpty(argList))
        csReturn.FormatV(csFormat, argList);

    va_end( argList );

    return csReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. There is no way to tell how many, or what type of, arguments were passed through ellipses, so you need some other means, such as a `printf` format string, to pass that information.

In C++11, you can do something very similar, using a variadic template:

```
template <typename... Args>
CString ADString::Format(CString csFormat, Args... argList)
{
    CString csReturn;

    //If it's empty, don't send to FormatV
    if(sizeof... argList != 0)
        csReturn.FormatV(csFormat, argList...);    

    return csReturn;
}
```